# Der Himmel hatte aufgeklart?

Tags: verb

Ich hörte eben in einem Hörbuch

> 1. Der Himmel hatte aufgeklart

Im ersten Moment fand ich, es fehle ein „sich“:

> 2. Der Himmel hatte sich aufgeklart

Dann fand ich, man könne vielleicht auch sagen

> 3. Der Himmel war aufgeklart

Für 3 fand ich dann über [Google](https://www.google.at/search?client=safari&hl=en-gb&ei=deo5W5KxDZCy0gXk-aroBw&q=der%20himmel%20war%20aufgeklart&oq=der%20himmel%20war%20aufgeklart&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.12...0.0..715450...0....0.0.......0.KwmPgywx85M%3D) Treffer in neueren (Jugend?)Büchern.

Die [Google Suche nach Variante 1](https://www.google.at/search?client=safari&hl=en-gb&ei=ku05W5_-IM7SwQLQl7SYBw&q=der%20himmel%20hatte%20aufgeklart&oq=der%20himmel%20hatte%20aufgeklart&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..30i10.49264.50346..51381...0....212.725.1j3j1......0....1.........0i7i30j0i8i13i30.GXLUN9aM6Ps%3D)  liefert Ergebnisse aus neueren Büchern sowohl für Variante 2, als auch 1. Alle drei Formen sind daher weiter verbreitet.

Der Duden schreibt bei „aufklaren“: „Perfektbildung mit *hat*“, allerdings liefert er keine meteorologischen Beispiele im Perfekt oder Plusquamperfekt. Das Verb steht nicht im Grimm. 
Diese [Suche im Corpus](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=aufgeklart) zeigt eine deutliche Dominanz von Typ 3, allerdings an wenigen, modernen Beispielen.
Daher meine Frage:

Sind alle drei Formen älter? Gibt es Beispiele aus der klassischen Literatur? Kann man eine Trennung zwischen Norden und Süden feststellen (wie das der Atlas der Deutschen Sprache gern tut)?

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hatte%20aufgeklart%2C%20hatte%20sich%20aufgeklart%2C%20war%20aufgeklart&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) hat leider nicht funktioniert. Vielleicht habe ich etwas falsch gemacht?

---

Edit: Meine bisherige Suche in klassischer Literatur:

0 Treffer für „aufgeklart“ im Gesamtwerk von Theodor Storm

0 Treffer in Grimms »Kinder und Hausmärchen«

0 Treffer in »Grimms Märchen: Deutsche Sagen«

0 Treffer im Gesamtwerk Goethes. Dafür gleich deren 76 für „aufgeklärt“ ;)

0 Treffer im Gesamtwerk Schillers, aber dafür in »Schiller’s (sic) Leben« von Gustav Schwab, Zweites Buch, »Schillers Todesfeier zu Hellebeck« der Satz:

> In Hellebeck, sechstehalb Meilen nördlich von Kopenhagen, am »naturgrößesten Ort,« am Meeresufer, dem Kullen, dem höchsten Felsen Schwedens gegenüber, saßen bei aufgeklärtem Himmel sechs sich liebende, fürs Gute begeisterte Menschen, und Baggesen fing an in tiefer Trauer zu lesen:...

Hier wird also „aufklaren“ nicht von „aufklären“ unterschieden, worin vielleicht die Argumentation der Nachschlagewerke gründet!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ich frage mich, ob sich die Dominanz von Typ 3, die man auch in den Links weiter oben sieht, erst in den letzten Jahrzehnten herausgebildet hat, oder ob diese „Standardvariante“ noch nie verbreitet war! Schade, dass ich Ngram nicht einspannen kann!

Answer (score 3):

["Aufklaren"](https://dwds.de/wb/aufklaren) ist ein ganz normales (schwaches, nicht reflexives) Verb, welches auch der Duden kennt. "Hatte aufgeklart" ist in dem Fall das Plusquamperfekt in dritter Person Singular von aufklaren.

Aufklaren bedeutet nichts anderes, als dass die Wolken vom Himmel verschwunden sind.

Aufklaren ist nicht zu verwechseln mit "sich aufklären".

Im Süden (zumindest in Bayern) ist der Audruck definitiv nicht üblich, in Niedersachsen habe ich ihn aber schon oft gehört und weiß daher auch definitiv, dass das Wort auch heutzutage noch verwendet wird.

Comment: Herzlich willkommen! Das weiß ich. Die Frage ist: bilden die Sachsen das Plusquamperfekt wie im Duden vorgesehen mit „haben“, oder nutzen sie eine der andere Möglichkeiten? Der Crawler, den ich oben zitierte fand hauptsächlich Beispiele mit „sein“...

Comment: "Hatte aufgeklart / hatte sich aufgeklart" beschreibt den Vorgang. Das "sich" ist optional, aber ich als aus dem Sprachraum Mitteldeutschland würde es schon verwenden im Sprachgebrauch. "War aufgeklart" beschreibt dagegen das Ergebnis des Vorgangs.

Answer (score 2):

Falls es nicht einfach ein Tippfehler ist, so handelt es sich um den Rest einer alten Zweiförmigkeit bei deadjektivalen (aus einem Adjektiv gebildeten) Verben. Ein transitives Verb mit Umlaut und kausativer Bedeutung (etwas so-und-so machen), und daneben ein intransitives Verb mit Zustands- (so-und-so sein) oder inchoativer Bedeutung (so-und-so werden). Beispiele:

- warm → [wärmen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=waermen) (warm machen) vs. [warmen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=warmen) (warm sein/werden)
- stark → [stärken](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=staerken) (stark machen) vs. [starken](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=starken) (stark sein/werden)
- kühl → [kühlen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=kuehlen) (kühl machen) vs. [kuhlen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=kuhlen) (kühl sein/werden)
- blind → [blenden](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=blenden) (blind machen) vs. [erblinden](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=erblinden) (blind sein/werden)
- klar → [klären](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=klaeren) (klar machen) vs. [klaren](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=klaren) (klar sein/werden)

Diese Zweiförmigkeit geht auf unterschiedliche Endungen im Althochdeutschen zurück. Heute ist sie nur noch regional lebendig, etwa in Teilen der Schweiz und vermutlich auch andernorts (wie oft bei Reliktformen).

Beide Arten von Verben nehmen das Hilfsverb *haben.*